# How to fix "rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (131)"?

Tags: rsync

Trying to transfer a file to a remote rsync daemon (rsyncd), the `rsync` client command fails with:

```
rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (131)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(785) [sender=3.1.2]
```

The exit/error code is 10. According to `man`, error 10 means socket i/o error.

How to fix this error code 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure a log file in your rsyncd.conf (rsync daemon configuration file) like:

> log file = /opt/var/log/rsync.log

Then restart `rsync --daemon`.
Run the faulty command again.
And have a look at the log file:

```
# tail /opt/var/log/rsync.log
```

The rsync daemon log file lists:

> 2017/06/30 02:13:27 [1210] ERROR: module is read only
>
> 2017/06/30 02:13:27 [1210] rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(994) [Receiver=3.1.2]

That gives the clue to add this line in rsyncd.conf to the corresponding module section:

```
read only = no
```